# Type aliases screw up type tags?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

Why don't type tags work with type aliases. E.g. given

```
trait Foo
object Bar {
  def apply[A](implicit tpe: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A]): Bar[A] = ???
}
trait Bar[A]
```

I would like to use an alias within the following method, because I need to type `A` around two dozen times:

```
def test {
  type A = Foo
  implicit val fooTpe = reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[A] // no funciona
  Bar[A]                                                   // no funciona
}
```

Next try:

```
def test {
  type A = Foo
  implicit val fooTpe = reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[Foo] // ok
  Bar[A]                                                     // no funciona
}
```

So it seems I can't be using my alias at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use weakTypeOf instead. Reflection internally distinguishes globally visible and local declarations, so you need to treat them differently as well. This wart may be removed in later versions of Scala.

Comment: Ok. But do I need to change the declaration site as well? Because I don't seem to get an implicit conversion from the type returned by `weakTypeOf` to `TypeTag[A]`. E.g.  `found : reflect.runtime.universe.Type ; required: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A]` (when calling `Bar[A](fooTpe)`)

Comment: Allright, seems I overlooked something when answering from my phone. First of all, the result of both `typeOf` and `weakTypeOf` is a `Type`, not a `TypeTag`, so `fooTpe` doesn't fit into `Bar.apply`.

Comment: Secondly, you can get rid of `weakTypeOf` altogether and change `TypeTag[A]` to `WeakTypeTag[A]`. After that it'll work fine.

Comment: Ok, it works when I use __both__ `weakTypeOf` and `WeakTypeTag`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `def apply` declaration:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
trait Foo
object Bar {
  def apply[A]()(implicit tpe: TypeTag[A]): Bar[A] = ???
}
trait Bar[A]
class test {
  type A = Foo
  implicit val foo = typeOf[A]
  def test = Bar[A]()                                                 
}
```

Comment: The `apply` doesn't matter. Your example seems to work because you move the type alias to a **class member level** (`def test` becomes `class test`). It seems broken as a method local type alias somehow -- very strange....