# In scala 2.13, why sometimes TypeTags cannot be inferred? And how to construct one from a variable symbol?

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-reflect, scala-2.13

Here is a simple example in shapeless:

```
  it("from Witness") {

    val ttg = implicitly[TypeTag[Witness.Lt[String]]]
    val ctg = implicitly[ClassTag[Witness.Lt[String]]]
  }

  it("... from macro") {

    val ttg = implicitly[TypeTag[Witness.`1`.T]]
    val ctg = implicitly[ClassTag[Witness.`1`.T]]
  }

  it("... doesn't work") {

    val ttg = implicitly[TypeTag[w1.T]] // failed!
    val ctg = implicitly[ClassTag[w2.T]]
  }
```

The second and third `it` block have very similar bytecode (after the Witness.`?` macro has been invoked), yet one succeed and one failed:

```
[Error] /home/peng/git-spike/scalaspike/common/src/test/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/scala_spike/Reflection/InferTypeTag.scala:55: No TypeTag available for com.tribbloids.spike.scala_spike.Reflection.InferTypeTag.w1.T
```

What could have caused this? And how do I circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you switch on `scalacOptions += "-Xlog-implicits"` you'll see

```
val w1 = Witness(1)
val ttg = implicitly[TypeTag[w1.T]] // doesn't compile

//materializing requested reflect.runtime.universe.type.TypeTag[App.w1.T] using scala.reflect.api.`package`.materializeTypeTag[App.w1.T](scala.reflect.runtime.`package`.universe)

//scala.reflect.api.`package`.materializeTypeTag[App.w1.T](scala.reflect.runtime.`package`.universe) is not a valid implicit value for reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[App.w1.T] because:
//failed to typecheck the materialized tag: 
//cannot create a TypeTag referring to type shapeless.Witness.<refinement>.T local to the reifee: use WeakTypeTag instead

//No TypeTag available for App.w1.T
```

So try to use `WeakTypeTag` as recommended

```
val w1 = Witness(1)
val ttg2 = implicitly[WeakTypeTag[w1.T]] // compiles
```

[In Scala, why it is impossible to infer TypeTag from type alias or dependent type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708880/in-scala-why-it-is-impossible-to-infer-typetag-from-type-alias-or-dependent-typ)

[Why there is no TypeTag available in nested instantiations (when interpreted by scala code runner)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866866/why-there-is-no-typetag-available-in-nested-instantiations-when-interpreted-by)

[Typetags not working inside of code block scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507760/typetags-not-working-inside-of-code-block-scope)

[Type aliases screw up type tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678292/type-aliases-screw-up-type-tags)

Comment: I can't see what makes WeakTypeTag a necessity: TypeTag guarantees that you have a concrete type (i.e. one which doesn't contain any type parameters or abstract type membershttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435985/weaktypetag-v-typetag ). w1.T clearly has a concrete type and it is "Int(1)"

Comment: In addition there might be a bug affecting the usability of WeakTypeTag derived this way, see https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/issues/1067